# Read 4D array with numpy from .txt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I generate a 4D array contained in a .txt file which looks like this:

```
[ [ [ [2.47, 1.57], [2.23, 5.95], [0.06, 2.54] ],

[ [0.79, 0.14], [1.64, 2.17], [0.86, 3.53] ],

[ [0.44, 3.42], [1.64, 5.39], [1.57, 2.63] ] ],


[ [ [2.34, 1.57], [0.75, 2.01], [2.86, 1.04] ],

[ [0.77, 1.25], [2.25, 6.08], [2.42, 0.51] ],

[ [1.44, 1.62], [2.44, 3.67], [2.99, 2.75] ] ],


[ [ [1.01, 3.35], [0.81, 0.29], [1.59, 4.37] ],

[ [0.29, 5.70], [0.10, 0.96], [3.08, 3.90] ],

[ [0.94, 2.27], [1.51, 1.87], [0.90, 5.81] ] ] ]
```

It's formatted this way because it's easy for me to create it like this. But, because of the brackets, I can't manage to use numpy.loadtxt() to load it correctly as a correct 4D array in python. How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to read the string as a variable for numpy array and use pathlib to read the entire file content as a string and then close the file in a single line, likewise:

```
import numpy as np
import ast
from pathlib import Path

arr_str = Path('./text.txt').read_text()
arr = np.array(ast.literal_eval(arr_str))
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a legitimate Python code. Then read it and evaluate to convert into a list:

```
with open("some.txt") as f:
    l = eval(f.read())
a = np.array(l)
```

`l` is the list with the contents of the file

`a` is the desired 4-D array.